# Cannot perform SELECT COUNT(*), rows over 1 billion on a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delete

I have this table that contains over a billion rows and to issue the query, I issued:

```
SELECT
   Total_Rows= SUM(st.row_count)
FROM
   sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
WHERE
    object_name(object_id) = 'audit_tb' AND (index_id < 2)

Output:
1055075195
```

I was asked to DELETE records in 2014 so to test out, I tried Deleting the last 3 months in 2014, it's been over 1 hr and it's still executing, any ideas?  I suspect there are bad rows.

```
 DELETE 
  FROM [audit_tb]
  where datetime >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00' 
  AND datetime <= '2014-03-31 00:00:00' --3 months in 2014
```

The table also has a CLUSTERED INDEX.

Comment: Can you add the table definition, including indexes? How many rows will be deleted by your query? You might need to delete in chunks.

Comment: SQL Server? Version? Execution plan? Partitions?

Comment: Evergreen: http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script to delete in chunks. It deletes in chunks of 4500 records to avoid lock escalation. It performs 100 loops to delete a total of 450,000 rows.
If your database is using the FULL recovery model, you may want to backup the transaction log after each run to keep if from growing too large.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @continue INT
DECLARE @rowcount INT
DECLARE @loopCount INT
DECLARE @MaxLoops INT
DECLARE @TotalRows BIGINT
DECLARE @PurgeBeginDate DATETIME
DECLARE @PurgeEndDate DATETIME

SET @PurgeBeginDate = '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
SET @PurgeEndDate = '2014-03-31 23:59:59'

SET @MaxLoops = 100
SET @continue = 1
SET @loopCount = 0

SELECT @TotalRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM audit_tb (NOLOCK) WHERE datetime between @PurgeBeginDate and @PurgeEndDate)
PRINT 'Total Rows = ' + CAST(@TotalRows AS VARCHAR(20))
PRINT ''

WHILE @continue = 1 
BEGIN
    SET @loopCount = @loopCount + 1
    PRINT 'Loop # ' + CAST(@loopCount AS VARCHAR(10))
    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 120)

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE TOP (4500) audit_tb WHERE datetime between @PurgeBeginDate and @PurgeEndDate
        SET @rowcount = @@rowcount 
    COMMIT

    PRINT 'Rows Deleted: ' + CAST(@rowcount AS VARCHAR(10))
    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 120)
    PRINT ''

    IF @rowcount = 0 OR @loopCount >= @MaxLoops
    BEGIN
        SET @continue = 0
    END
END

SELECT @TotalRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM audit_tb (NOLOCK) WHERE datetime between @PurgeBeginDate and @PurgeEndDate)
PRINT 'Total Rows Remaining = ' + CAST(@TotalRows AS VARCHAR(20))
PRINT ''


GO
```

I have used this in a SQL Agent job to run repeatedly until the required number of rows were removed. I just schedule the job to run every 15 minutes so my tran log backup job runs between runs of this job.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you MillhouseD and Paparazzi.  I did a select count just referencing within a day and it was just executing forever.  Even if I delete in chunks, I'm not sure how long this would take.  This table has an application, we will speak with a vendor this week and see what we can do.  Can we move to a chat room?

Comment: You are welcome @DennisM. You might have better results if you create a non-clustered index on the datetime column. You could drop the index after the deletes are complete. Here is sample syntax: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_audit_tb_datetime ON dbo.audit_tb (datetime ASC) ` I would be happy to move to a chat room.

Comment: Why are you performing a select count - it has nothing to do the the delete.  Delete top X does not need to perform a count.

Comment: You are correct in that it has nothing to do with the delete. It is for logging the before and after counts. If I have hundreds of millions of rows to delete I like to see how many are left in the job history.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 1 
while (@@rowcount > 0)
begin 
  DELETE top (100000) 
  FROM [audit_tb]
  where datetime >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00' 
    AND datetime <  '2015-01-01 00:00:00' 
end
```

You can adjust the 100000 but that is a good starting point